HuggingFace tokens for 'model garden' not valid in Google console
I'm trying to use one of the "model Garden" items from HuggingFace in Vertex, as per:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/open-models/use-hugging-face-models
but when I select the "Model Garden", "HuggingFace", and put in a token I have verified with the HuggingFace CLI, the GCP UI is not accepting a valid HuggingFace token
:-(
Has anyone else encountered this problem?
picture of GCP console
Model garden
